# What will be the return statement of a method, which creates an array of size n, with return type Integer[]?

Tags: java, arrays, interface, return-type

I'm having trouble understanding how to return an array of user defined size in a method which return type is `Integer[]`. The class which contains this method extends an interface, if that makes any difference here (I don't think it does, but correct me if I'm wrong).

When trying to return a, java tells me the type is incompatible. I'm not sure if the problem lies in my method body, or if there's a particular way to phrase the return statement since the return type is `Integer[]`. I need to return the array without assigning a value to size, as size will be assigned a value in the main method. Please advise and explain what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks in advance!

```java
@Override
public Integer[] generateTestDataBinary(int size) {
    Comparable[] a = new Comparable[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (size <= size/2) {
            a[i] = 0;
        }
        else {
            a[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

This array will be used to test the time complexity of different sorting algorithms. I have to create two more arrays after this one, each one slightly different than the last, so I need to know how to implement this method in order to finish the program. Please let me know if more code is needed to understand the context of the problem.

Comment: You're declaring that you're returning an `Integer[]`, but you're creating and attempting to return a `Comparable[]`.

Comment: When do you expect `size <= size/2` to ever be true? I mean, for anything other than `size = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

An `Integer[]` is `Comparable[]`, but a `Comparable[]` is not an `Integer[]`.

Change your type from `Comparable[]` to `Integer[]`.

Answer (score 0):

See [`java.lang.Comparable`'s API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> **All Known Implementing Classes:**
>
> ..., [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), ...

and [`java.lang.Integer`'s API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html):

> **All Implemented Interfaces:**
>
> ..., [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

That means an `Integer` *is* a `Comparable` but a `Comparable` *is not* an `Integer`. You cannot assign a value of a super-type (`Comparable`) to a variable of a sub-type (`Integer`). Likewise, you cannot return a value of a super-type (`Comparable`) from a method of a sub-type (`Integer`) be it an array or not:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Comparable[] to Integer[]

The reason is: A super-type doesn't know anything about the extensions of its sub-type(s) (remember the class declaration syntax `class <sub-type> extends <super-type>`). Hence, assigning an object with less information (the super-type) to an object variable that is supposed to hold and has according space for more information (the sub-type) would lead to undefined areas.

So, the following compile:

```java
public Integer[] generateTestDataBinary(int size) {
  Integer[] a = new Integer[size];
  // ...
  return a;
}
```

```java
public Comparable<Integer>[] generateTestDataBinary(int size) {
  Integer[] a = new Integer[size];
  // ...
  return a;
}
```

```java
public Comparable<Integer>[] generateTestDataBinary(int size) {
  Comparable<Integer>[] a = new Comparable[size];
  // ...
  return a;
}
```